# Restbed set_path() for unknown number of params?

Tags: c++, rest, restbed

Can you allow a path with known `params` to have an additional number of unknown `params` in the [Restbed API](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed)?  As of right now it looks like you must declare each `param`.

**Example:**

```
known:(http://restbed.com/endpoint/) + unknown(params/number/and/value/set/by.user)
```

Answer (score 1):

We replied to your [ticket](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed/issues/88) on the project issue tracker some time ago.

Comment: Answer: No feature currently exist.